# I have a problem reading the input from console and outputting a String after it?

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86, masm

I am trying to get an input from the console, but after I read something from the console I can't print anything out anymor, there is a little pause after i read it.

It tryed increasing and deacreasing the inputBuffersize

```
    invoke  GetStdHandle, -11
    mov     stdoutHandle, eax ; Save the console output handl    
    mov     ebx, stdoutHandle 
    lea     eax, inoutSTR  ; Load the address of the strV character into eax
    push    0             
    push    0             
    push    SIZEOF inoutSTR
    CALL printEAX


   ; Read user input from the console
    invoke  GetStdHandle, -10
    mov     ebx, eax
    lea     eax, inputBuffer
    push    0
    push    0
    push    SIZEOF inputBuffer
    push    eax
    push    ebx
    call    ReadConsoleA


    ; Print the strV to the console
    mov     ebx, stdoutHandle        ; Save the console input handle in ebx
    lea     eax, inoutSTR  ; Load the address of the strV character into eax
    push    0             
    push    0             
    push    SIZEOF inoutSTR
    CALL printEAX
```

```
    inputBuffer     BYTE    4 DUP(0) ; Buffer to hold the user input
```

Comment: I am trying to learn more low-level programming, so it could be a stupid mistake but ChatGPT doesn't help much with masm and I have no clue what the problem could be, so any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Did you read more than 4 bytes, perhaps overwriting `stdoutHandle` if it comes after it in memory?  IDK why you keep putting different values in EBX; you could just put the handle for stdout there and leave it unchanged.  EBX is call-preserved in standard calling conventions.  (But IDK what your `printEAX` does since you haven't show it.)  You don't need the stdin handle in EBX, you can just push EAX at the appropriate time.  (You have other free regs for the address of inputBuffer, but you don't need a register to push a symbol address in 32-bit code; `push OFFSET inputBuffer`)

Comment: Invokation of [ReadConsoleA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) is incorrect. The 4th parameter *lpNumberOfCharsRead* expects pointer to DWORD instead of NULL. You should always check the Return value of *ReadConsole*. Also be sure that *inputBuffer* is in a writeble section (not in **.text**).

Comment: Thanks i read the Windows docs again for the function and fund the Bug myself but thatnks for the answer